# Why this code works for 8 different test cases except 1 in C++?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, if-statement

So I wrote this function in C++ which basically counts the maximum number in an array and then prints out the number of maximum numbers in the array. Here's the code of the function:

```
int Number_of_maxNum(vector<int> ar) {
      int max=0;
      int Number_of_Maxnum=0;
      int d = ar.size();

      for(int i=0;i<=d;i++){
          if(ar[i]>max){
          max=ar[i];
          }
      }

      for(int j=0;j<=d;j++){
          if(ar[j]==max){
             Number_of_Maxnum++;
          }
      }

      return Number_of_Maxnum;

}
```

Now this code however doesn't work for the following array as input:
{44, 53, 31, 27, 77, 60, 66, 77, 26, 36}
It should print out 2, but print out 1

If someone could please explain what's actually going on with that input that's giving 1 as an input, It would

Comment: Please, if the current answer is the right one, check it as the correct answer. ;-)

Comment: I thinks its because of size you are giving to for loop. You should make it as ```j<d``` because array has spaces from 0-n-1. And what may be happening is you are getting a big garbage value which is greater than all numbers and hence you are getting 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Undefined Behaviour. Arrays/vectors are indexed from `0` to `Size-1`. So change `i<=d` to `i<d`. This is most likely the reason for this strange result. Because you read your vector outside of its boundary, resulting in (effectively) random last value (note that this is UB, it can even crash your entire program).

Another thing is that you should initialize `int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();` unless you guarantee that all elements of `ar` are nonnegative.

Finally you can do entire processing in a single loop. Try this:

```cpp
int Number_of_maxNum(const vector<int>& ar)  // <--- do this to avoid vector copy
{
      int currentMax = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
      int counter = 0;
      for (int value : ar)  // <--- do this to avoid error prone manual indexing
      {
          if (value == currentMax)
          {
              counter++;
          }
          else if (value > currentMax)
          {
              currentMax = value;
              counter = 1;
          }
      }
      return counter;
}
```

Comment: He is a beginner, your code is probably too complex for him. :)

Comment: @Apitronix that's why in the first paragraph I gave him quick simple fix, while later a proper solution. Aim high, my friend, never low. :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is certainly correct, as well as explaining why your code is wrong.

However, you should also consider using the STL to do what you need, like this

```
int Number_of_maxNum(const std::vector<int>& ar)  
{
  if (ar.size() == 0)
    return 0;

  auto max = *std::max_element(ar.cbegin(), ar.cend());

  return std::count(ar.cbegin(), ar.cend(), max);
}
```

Some of the advantages are:

1. It's easier to read (and write, once you're used to it).
2. There's no issues with off-by-one errors (as you had in your solution).
3. No worrying about initializing the maximum number to be the smallest possible number.

One disadvantage of this solution is that it loops over the vector twice. This can still be avoided by using the appropriate algorithm, e.g.

```
int Number_of_maxNum(const std::vector<int>& ar)  
{
  return std::accumulate(ar.cbegin(), ar.cend(), 0, 
          [max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()]  
          (int count, int num) mutable {
             return num > max ? max = num, 1 : count + (num == max);
  });
}
```

This is effectively the conventional for-loop, so I'm not sure there's much to be gained by writing it this way. Also, mutable lambdas could be considered a code smell. You should use your judgement to decide which technique to use, once you are aware of the options.

Comment: A disadvantage: you loop twice over the vector.

Comment: @freakish that's true. I've updated the answer to reflect that.